# How to traverse nested array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save path for each of the node by traversing from root node to the leaf node.

For example, I have nodes like this in hierarchical structure :

```
Node - 1
     Node-1-1
       Node-1-1-1
```

**Expected output for each node:**

```
So for Node - 1 I would like to have value in property path : /myPath/Node - 1
So for Node-1-1 I would like to have value in property path : /myPath/Node - 1/Node-1-1
So for Node-1-1-1 I would like to have value in property path : /myPath/Node - 1/Node-1-1/Node-1-1-1
```

But path I am getting is like below with my code for **Node-1-1-1**:

```
"/myPath/Node-1-1-1"
```

But expected out is like below :

```
/myPath/Node - 1/Node-1-1/Node-1-1-1  (becuase Node-1-1-1 belongs to Node-1-1 but Node-1-1 in turn belongs to Node - 1).
```

Demo:

```js
var  tree =  JSON.parse('[{"name":"Node","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1-1","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1-1-1","nodes":[],"path":null}],"path":null}],"path":null}],"path":null}]');

traverseTree(tree);
console.log(tree);
 function traverseTree(nodes)
    {
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        node.path= getPath(node.name) 
            if (node.nodes) {
                traverseTree(node.nodes);
            }
        });
    }
    
    function getPath(name)
    {
       var path = "/myPath/";
       path = path + name;
       return path;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all nodes in the path and use the array then for getting the whole path to the node.

```js
var  tree =  JSON.parse('[{"name":"Node","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1-1","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1-1-1","nodes":[],"path":null}],"path":null}],"path":null}],"path":null}]');

function traverseTree(nodes, path) {
    path = path || [];
    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        node.path = getPath(path.concat(node.name));
        if (node.nodes) {
            traverseTree(node.nodes, path.concat(node.name));
        }
    });
}
    
function getPath(name) {
   var path = "/myPath/";
   path = path + name.join('/');
   return path;
}

traverseTree(tree);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Shorter version with a given prefix

```js
var  tree =  JSON.parse('[{"name":"Node","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1-1","nodes":[{"name":"Node-1-1-1","nodes":[],"path":null}],"path":null}],"path":null}],"path":null}]');

function traverseTree(nodes, path) {
    path = path || [];
    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        var p = path.concat(node.name);
        node.path = p.join('/')
        if (node.nodes) {
            traverseTree(node.nodes, p);
        }
    });
}

traverseTree(tree, ['', 'myPath']);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much mam for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this.Once again thank you so much :)